# ANSYS APDL: How to select elements with Jacobian error

Tags: ansys-apdl

I work on a huge FE model that shows one element with Jacobian error in shape check Summary. How can i find the number of this one? Or select it somehow to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Mechanical APDL help on the CHECK command.  It has an field "SELE" that you can use, by setting the field to ESEL, to select the elements that fail the shape checking (or give a waring).  The when plotting the elements just the failed elements are shown.
Mike